# How do you figure out what the older versions are for a particular Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How do you figure out what the older versions are for a particular Ruby Gem?

I need to revert to an older version of the rack gem but I'm not sure which versions are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the gem command for this, like so:

```
gem query --remote -a -n ^rack$
```

The -n switch of query restricts the search by regular expression, so in this case you only get the gem whose name exactly matches the string "rack".

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
http://rubyforge.org/projects/#{gem_name}/
```

Click on 'Files' in the navbar and look at what `.gem` files are available. Those files are the official source of Rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to know the old versions you have installed, use gem list:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.2)
actionpack (2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.2)
activerecord (2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.2)
...
```